# How to introduce Stripe to Firebase

Tags: firebase, npm, stripe-payments

I am having trouble introducing Firebase into Stripe.

1. I have already deployed.
2. I am trying to this one (https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments), and I have trouble in this phase.

I have already done 3.1 in the URL, but when I put `npm install -g` in functions, I get the error message below.

Can someone help me?

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/Takahiro/Desktop/RepFit-master/functions
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10

npm ERR! No version provided in package.json
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /Users/×××/Desktop/×××（site name）/functions/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I have a feeling that it should just be `npm install`, without the `-g` part. That's what the instructions from the FireStripe repo said: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe#deploy-and-test

Comment: Dear all Thank you so much for your comment. And I just try what you tell me, and it works. Sorry for bothering this easy question. But for me, it is very helpful.

Comment: Glad to help, good luck with your app! :D